# SQL SERVER STUFF FUNCTION VALUE INCREMENT COUNTER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to Add Counter  in this query any idea ?

```
SELECT 
STUFF((
    SELECT ' , vol' + counter +' : ' + t2.ViaLocValue  
    FROM Book_ViaLocat t2
    WHERE t2.BookId = t1.BookId
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS Names
FROM Book_ViaLocat t1
WHERE t1.BookId = '167698'
GROUP BY t1.BookId;
```

result like this
    vol 1 : java2 , vol 2 : java3, vol 3 : java4

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved, especially not when using product specific stuff.

Comment: Referring to this as "Stuff function" is to massively miss the point of what this code does. `FOR XML PATH ('')` concatenates a number of values together into a comma separated string. `STUFF(<value>,1,2,'')` removes the first two characters (the leading comma) from that result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER():

```
SELECT 
STUFF((
    SELECT ' ,vol' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t2.ViaLocValue) AS VARCHAR(4))+
           ' : ' + t2.ViaLocValue  
    FROM Booking_ViaLocat t2
    WHERE t2.BookingId = t1.BookId
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS Names
FROM Booking_ViaLocat t1
WHERE t1.BookId = '167698'
GROUP BY t1.BookId;
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be possible by using "ROW_NUMBER()", u can sort your table value according to your wish also (change it on roder by if you want so)..
follow the below code :)

```
SELECT 
STUFF((
    SELECT ' ,vol' + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.BookId asc) AS Row +' : ' + t2.ViaLocValue  
    FROM Booking_ViaLocat t2
    WHERE t2.BookingId = t1.BookId
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS Names
FROM Booking_ViaLocat t1
WHERE t1.BookId = '167698'
GROUP BY t1.BookId;
```

Comment: please note that ROW_NUMBER return data as int - need cast into string

Comment: no need :/ it's working fine ... better check one more time by you

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near '+'.